# Prevent scrolling to next component until animation complete using framer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I'm quite new to `framer-motion` and am using it to recreate the Starfield effect on the homepage of Repl.it (logged-out version).

Essentially, when you load the website, a starfield shows up with some text on top of it. As you scroll, the speed of the stars in the starfield increase, and the text gets bigger and has higher opacity. This continue until text is fully faded out and stars are quite fast. Continuing to scroll after this point brings the user to the actual next section of the website.

My implementation looks like this:

```
import {
  domAnimation,
  LazyMotion,
  m,
  useScroll,
  useTransform,
} from 'framer-motion';
import React from 'react';

import { StarField } from './StarField';

export const StarCanvas: React.FC = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScroll();
  const scale = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 1500], [1, 2]);
  const opacity = useTransform(scrollY, [0, 1500], [1, 0]);
  return (
    <LazyMotion features={domAnimation}>
      <div className="sticky top-0 flex h-screen w-full items-center justify-center">
        <StarField />
        <m.div style={{ scale, opacity }} className="z-10">
          <h1 className="text-center text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight sm:text-5xl lg:text-7xl">
            <span className="block text-black">Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
            <span className="block text-black">set amet</span>
          </h1>
          <p className="mx-auto mt-6 max-w-lg text-center text-xl text-gray-700 sm:max-w-3xl">
           Lorem ipsum dolor set amet. This is great.
          </p>
          <div className="mx-auto mt-10 flex max-w-lg flex-col items-center justify-center gap-4 sm:flex-row">
            <a href="#" className="inverse-btn btn-thick">
              Button One
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="main-btn btn-thick">
              Button Two
            </a>
          </div>
        </m.div>
      </div>
    </LazyMotion>
  );
};
```

`StarField` here is the canvas where the stars are drawn.

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
import { useReducedMotion, useScroll, useTransform } from 'framer-motion';
import * as React from 'react';

import { useWindowSize } from './useWindowSize';

const NUM_STARS = 3000;

export const StarField = () => {
  const { scrollY } = useScroll();

  const { width, height } = useWindowSize();
  const windowWidth: number = width as number;
  const windowHeight: number = height as number;

  const prefersReducedMotion = useReducedMotion();

  const speed = useTransform(scrollY, [0, windowHeight * 3], [3, 100]);

  const requestId = React.useRef<number | undefined>(undefined);

  const ref = React.useCallback(
    (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement | null) => {
      stop();

      const ctx = canvas?.getContext('2d');
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.width = windowWidth;
        canvas.height = windowHeight;

        if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
          const currentWidth = canvas.width;
          const currentHeight = canvas.height;

          canvas.width = currentWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
          canvas.height = currentHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
          canvas.style.width = `${currentWidth}px`;
          canvas.style.height = `${currentHeight}px`;

          ctx?.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
        }
      }

      const canvasWidth = canvas?.width as number;
      const canvasHeight = canvas?.height as number;

      function randomX() {
        return Math.random() * canvasWidth - canvasWidth / 2;
      }

      function randomY() {
        return Math.random() * canvasHeight - canvasHeight / 2;
      }

      function randomZ() {
        return Math.random() * canvasWidth;
      }

      const stars: Array<Star> = [];
      const colors = [
        [87, 171, 255],
        [242, 224, 136],
        [255, 189, 122],
        [122, 235, 141],
        [166, 148, 255],
      ];

      const widthScale = windowWidth / 1440;

      type Star = ReturnType<typeof createStar>;
      function createStar() {
        let x = randomX();
        let y = randomY();
        let z = randomZ();
        let prevZ = z;
        const color =
          Math.random() < 0.75
            ? [245, 249, 252]
            : colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        return {
          update() {
            if (!prefersReducedMotion) {
              z -= speed.get() * widthScale;

              if (z < 1) {
                z = canvasWidth;
                x = randomX();
                y = randomY();
                prevZ = z;
              }
            }
          },

          show() {
            const alpha = 1 - z / canvasWidth;
            const newColor = `rgba(${color![0]!}, ${color![1]!}, ${color![2]!}, ${alpha})`;

            const rad = 24 * (1 - z / canvasWidth);

            const scaledX = (canvasWidth * x) / z;
            const scaledY = (canvasHeight * y) / z;

            const prevX = (canvasWidth * x) / prevZ;
            const prevY = (canvasHeight * y) / prevZ;

            prevZ = z;

            if (ctx) {
              ctx.lineWidth = rad;
              ctx.lineCap = 'round';
              ctx.strokeStyle = newColor;
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
              ctx.lineTo(scaledX, scaledY);
              ctx.stroke();
            }
          },
        };
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < NUM_STARS; i++) {
        stars.push(createStar());
      }

      function draw() {
        requestId.current = undefined;

        ctx?.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx?.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        ctx?.translate(canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);
        for (const star of stars) {
          star.update();
          star.show();
        }

        start();
      }

      function start() {
        if (requestId.current === undefined) {
          requestId.current = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
      }

      function stop() {
        if (requestId.current !== undefined) {
          window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId.current);
          requestId.current = undefined;
        }
      }

      draw();
    },
    [prefersReducedMotion, speed, windowHeight, windowWidth]
  );

  return <canvas className="absolute" ref={ref} />;
};
```

The `StarCanvas` component is placed in my page, and following it I have other React components.

My problem is, when I scroll, the speed of the stars increases and the text gets bigger and fades just right, but the website also actually scrolls down to the next component. I want to have the user be stuck to this "component" until the animation is complete (stars at max speed, text fully faded out) before continuing on to scroll to the next section of the landing page like Repl.it does - and I am not sure how to achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should have two containers, one that has a specified height based on how much the user should scroll (like for example 300vh, or 3 times screen height), and then another container with a sticky position that slides through that container.

Check this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ehYkfh7P-I

The best way to animate based in scroll is with this approach, not manipulating scroll events. Note: if you use sticky, any container should specify overflow behavior, because it doesn´t work properly